# My iOS app runs REALLY slow on iOS 5, what could it be?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, fmdb

Ok, I have a simple reader app that I've had on the store for a while, and it works great. I have a sqlite db of content and I use fmdb to talk to it. I load up my text and display it in a UIWebView. Pretty simple stuff.

When iOS 5 went live, I started getting emails about the app not running right. Sure enough, it is running VERY slow. I have a UISegmentedControl to toggle between chapters, it literally freezes the UI for 10 seconds before it does anything. There are a few other instances where this is the case.

What is going on? The app still works technically, but it is just so slow it is unusable. Has anyone else seen this? Does anybody have any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: Are you loading text upon app load, or while loading the UIWebView?

Comment: The text is coming in initially when the view loads, and then when it's ready it is loaded into the webView by an html string...it worked  perfectly before iOS 5, I just don't get what would be causing this. Could it be a bug of the OS? With a fix on the way?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your app.  I suggest the same thing as @ChrisParker: run your app through Instruments to find out what the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run your application under Instruments and let it tell where the program is spending most of its time. The time sampling tool should give you breakdown of the methods which are consuming the most number of samples for a given run.